# osm2pgsql-flex output: Lua dependecies 'dkjson' under windows10

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, windows-10

I'am using PostgrSQL 12 on a windows 10 machine. I need to import .pbf-files from OSM. I have a lua-script using the dkjson package:

```
local json = require('dkjson')
```

However if I use osm2pgsql it gives me:

```
ERROR: Error loading lua config: ...mylocalpath\myluafile.lua:4: module 'dkjson' not found:
        no field package.preload['dkjson']
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\lua\dkjson.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\lua\dkjson\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\dkjson.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\dkjson\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\..\share\lua\5.3\dkjson.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\..\share\lua\5.3\dkjson\init.lua'
        no file '.\dkjson.lua'
        no file '.\dkjson\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\dkjson.dll'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\..\lib\lua\5.3\dkjson.dll'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\dkjson.dll'
        no file 'C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql-bin\dkjson53.dll'
        no file '.\dkjson53.dll'.
```

I have the latest windows binary of osm2pgsql. I do not understand if Lua comes with osm2pgsql or do I have to install LuaRocks in order to make it work (I`d prefer not to).

Can someone explain if this is supposed to work standalone via osm2pgsql (i.e. if this is a problem with my binary or my windows) or point me in the right direction of how to make this work?

Comment: You need to install dkjson lua package first, it’s not part of osm2pgsql.

Comment: Also you should check if you really need dkjson: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/1458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

osm2pgsql can use Lua-packages if you store them in the osm2pgsql-bin folder.

In this case just store "dkjson.lua" from http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better ask this question on the osm2pgsql code development GitHub repository. There is little chance of receiving an answer here with such a specific question:

https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues